Make A Table Ignore Trivial Updates
The scenario:
I own an ETL process. That process involves ingesting data from disparate sources and making my database sync with the latest.
Let's say that I have a table called [catalog]. It contains my company's catalog of products.  The source of truth for this table sends me a CSV every four hours. I ingest that CSV and make sure my [catalog] table is sync'd with it. I use an update like this:
UPDATE mc 
SET
      [field1] = tc.[field1]
    , [field2] = tc.[field2]
FROM [my].[catalog] as mc  
INNER JOIN [their].[catalog] as tc
    ON mc.id = tc.id
WHERE mc.[field1] <> tc.[field1]
OR mc.[field2] <> tc.[field2]

This command will compare every match and filter out only those who will see meaningful change and updates those rows only. I don't want to touch any rows unnecessarily--the perennial task of ETL developers.
No trivial updates will be executed (by trivial update, I mean an update to a row that changes none of the fields in that row).
The rows without changes remain as they were, unmolested.
Unmolested is a good word to use here because updating a row while not impacting values comes at an unnecessary cost. In ram and at the disk, an update to a row physically deletes the row with the old values and inserts a new row with the new values. All of these updates have to be logged! So, in the process of doing nothing, we have fragmented and split the index and data pages that we have for the table in both ram and on disk. And we're putting unnecessary traffic through the log.
If we're not changing anything, then a trivial update is still causing churn in ram and on disk. Giving a table an automatic way to ignore trivial updates would be a big win for many scenarios.
Now, let's just say that some ham-fisted developer makes an update through some client or in a procedure change that does something similar to a large table but doesn't include any measures to ignore rows not 'really' needing the update.
Is there something that I can do to the table to make it act as if it knows to pass on trivial updates?

I really appreciate the contributions above. Thanks guys! The link to Paul White's article is really helpful. Thank you so much.
The solution that I have is to add a persisted calculated column to the table [row_hash]. It is the result of SQL Server's Hashbytes function.
An INSTEAD OF trigger allows me to bump the inserted and deleted psuedotables together by their keys and only act on rows that have a changed hash_column.
With the trigger in place, the table is more forgiving to a less initiated developer. And I can also trim out some of the overhead that I've been building with pretty much every MERGE statement that I write.
With the row_hash persisted and the INSTEAD OF trigger acting as the border collie, only the rows with actual change get changed.
The code for setting this up is in this document: https://github.com/islandmonk/update_only_when_changed/blob/main/row_hash%20infrastructure.sql
An example of is usage against a table with the following schema:
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[note](
          [note_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
        , [object_id] [int] NULL 
        , [column_id] [int] NULL 
        , [parent_note_id] [int] NULL 
        , [note] [nvarchar](max) NULL 
        , [created] [datetime] NOT NULL default(getdate())
    )  

The code necessary to set this up for ignoring redundant updates is this:
-- Add row_hash column to table [dbo].[note]
--
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[note] ADD row_hash as HASHBYTES('sha2_512', CONCAT(
      [object_id]
    , [column_id]
    , [parent_note_id]
    , [note]
    , [created])
) PERSISTED; 
GO



--------
-- INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger for [dbo].[note]
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo_note__instead_of_IUD ON [dbo].[note]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE 
AS
    /*
    This is the definition of an INSTEAD OF trigger. Its initial purpose is to reduce churn on tables
    mostly for the sake of performance. There is nothing stopping you from altering this trigger to
    add other functionality. Keep in mind, also, that you can have AFTER UPDATE triggers on the same
    table as one with an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. So that is still available to you even if you
    go with this approach.
    */

    UPDATE d
    SET 
          [object_id] = i.[object_id]
        , [column_id] = i.[column_id]
        , [parent_note_id] = i.[parent_note_id]
        , [note] = i.[note]
    FROM [dbo].[note] as d -- deleted
    INNER JOIN inserted as i 
        ON d.[note_id] = i.[note_id] 

    -- rows where there is no difference between inserted and deleted are redundant and ignored
    WHERE d.[row_hash] <> i.[row_hash] 


    -- Inserts proceed as usual

    INSERT [dbo].[note] (
          [object_id]
        , [column_id]
        , [parent_note_id]
        , [note]
        , [created]
    )
    SELECT 
          [object_id]
        , [column_id]
        , [parent_note_id]
        , [note]
        , [created]
    FROM inserted as i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM deleted as d
        WHERE d.[note_id] = i.[note_id]     
    )

    -- DELETES proceed as usual

    DELETE t 
    FROM [dbo].[note] as t -- target 
    INNER JOIN deleted as d
        ON d.[note_id] = i.[note_id] 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1
        FROM inserted as i
        WHERE d.[note_id] = i.[note_id]     
    )
GO
--------------




You should add which database system, version, and edition you're using...
...because your mileage may vary on some of the conclusions you've drawn, depending on those factors.
For Example:
SQL Server doesn't process redundant UPDATE statements, to different extents, under specific scenarios.
So your statements...

All of these updates have to be logged! So, in the process of doing nothing, we have fragmented and split the index and data pages that we have for the table in both ram and on disk. And we're putting unnecessary traffic through the log.
If we're not changing anything, then a trivial update is still causing churn in ram and on disk.

...are incorrect in some contexts.
Proof
Paul White wrote a very interesting blog post on this subject entitled The Impact of Non-Updating Updates. It's a short read, so highly recommend viewing it in its entirety. But some (don't want to give away all the juicy details) of the key points he summarizes at the end are:


Non-updating updates to a clustered table generally avoid extra logging and page flushing, unless a column that forms (part of) the clustering key is affected by the update operation.




Heap tables behave the same as clustered tables, except they do not have a cluster key to cause any extra logging or page flushing.
This remains the case even where a non-clustered primary key exists on the heap. Non-updating updates to a heap therefore generally avoid the extra logging and flushing (but see below)





Both heaps and clustered tables will suffer the extra logging and flushing for any row where a LOB column containing more than 8000 bytes of data is updated to the same value using any syntax other than SET column_name = column_name.


...seriously, don't trust me to have  copy & pasted correctly above, and go read Paul's article in full.
Therefore
At least in SQL Server, redundant updates also known as non-updating updates, don't always unnecessarily "cause churn in ram and on disk".
But It's Good To Be Explicit
Because not every case is guaranteed and things are liable to change in the future, either with how the database engine processes a non-updating UPDATE, or how your code and data evolves over time.
There's a few different ways you can go about trying to solve:

Is there something that I can do to the table to make it act as if it knows to pass on trivial updates?

Akina's answer is one option, though it'll still generate log records for deletes of the rows you remove upfront and requires a double pass to accomplish your goal.
Another option is to hash the row and materialize the hash value to a column so it can be indexed. Then you can compare your SourceTable and TargetTable on their keys where the hash values don't match, in a very efficient way, via a query such as:
UPDATE T
SET T.SomeField1 = S.SomeField1
FROM SourceTable AS S
INNER JOIN TargetTable AS T
    ON S.KeyField = T.KeyField -- Same row by key
    AND S.RowHash <> T.RowHash; -- But has changes

One pass, efficient comparison, no need to generate extra log records deleting the rows that aren't going to be used for the update because their values are redundant.
In the past I've used this technique for large datasets for similar problems. I particularly use the HASHBYTES() function to calculate the row hash, which is deterministic and can be stored either in a computed column or indexed view (if you don't want to modify the table schema). But again, your options here will depend on your database system, version, and edition.

Side Note

Unmolested is a good word to use here...

I think "unmolested" is a very poor choice of words in this context due to its usual connotations.

Thanks for this awesome response and the link to the article.!

@DougHills No problem! Best of luck!

You receive your CSV and save it to [their].[catalog] table.
As a first step delete those rows from this table which will cause "trivial updates".
DELETE FROM [their].[catalog] AS tc
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM [my].[catalog] AS mc
    WHERE mc.id = tc.id 
      AND mc.[field1] = tc.[field1] 
      AND mc.[field2] = tc.[field2]
    );

This query will use according composite indices very effectively. So do not forget to create those indices in your temporary table which contains actual data state received from your "source of truth".
After this deletion the table [their].[catalog] contains only those rows which will cause "practical updates", and you may update without additional filtering:
UPDATE mc 
SET [field1] = tc.[field1]
  , [field2] = tc.[field2]
FROM [my].[catalog] as mc  
INNER JOIN [their].[catalog] as tc
    ON mc.id = tc.id;

This query, again, may use according (primary?) indices effectively.
